# Count number of entries in multiple files with different name

Tags: unix, grep, wc

I have say file A.txt, B.txt, C.text in a folder. Each of the text file contain few entries.
How to count how many entries in each text file has? and also want to extract to a list with first column as name of text file and second column as no. of entries in corresponding file.
Thanks

Comment: And how the entries are written? Could you provide sample text file. Also what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

By "entries", do you mean "lines"? If so, here is a very basic and quick solution in bash:

```
files=(A.txt B.txt C.txt)
echo -e "File\tCount"
for i in "${files[@]}"
do
        ret=$(cat $i | wc -l)
        echo -e "$i\t$ret"
done
```

Here is the output:

```
File    Count
A.txt   2
B.txt   1
C.txt   1
```

If you make this into a script, you will probably want to get the list of files as a parameter.